# why my homebrew was installed on /usr/local/homebrew, not /usr/local?

Tags: installation, homebrew

i use a mac with intel chip and the mac os version is Sonoma (14.2), i want to install homebrew and i followed the instruction on the [homebrew github page](https://github.com/Homebrew/install) :
i use this command with zsh:
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` 
every thing is fine.
after successful installation, i run the command `brew doctor` and got this warning:

```
Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /usr/local.

Many of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default prefix.
Consider uninstalling Homebrew and reinstalling into the default prefix.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this unsupported configuration.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.
```

my questions is why installation folder  is not /usr/local? why /usr/local/homebrew now? how to change the installation folder?

i checked the scripts for installing:

```
if [[ "${UNAME_MACHINE}" == "arm64" ]]
  then
    # On ARM macOS, this script installs to /opt/homebrew only
    HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"
    HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}"
  else
    # On Intel macOS, this script installs to /usr/local only
    HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/usr/local"
    HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/Homebrew"
```

the location is 'usr/local'